# All ports being assigned to one container when scaling with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The problem is: *When I run docker-compose with the scale flag (for multiple containers) it just creates one container and it has all the ports available in docker-compose.yml*

I try to run "docker-compose up" with the scale parameter so I can run three containers with a different exposed port in the host for each one:

> docker-compose up --scale minecraft=2

After running that command I receive this error:

> Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:25566: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

When I run docker PS I see that only one container is running and its taking all the ports

```
e87a404ab7d0   itzg/minecraft-server   "/start"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:25565->25565/tcp, 25575/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25566->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25567->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25568->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25569->25565/tcp, 0.0.0.0:25570->25565/tcp   docker-minecraft-minecraft-1
```

I have a docker-compose.yml config file where I have availability for more than one port so I don't know the reason of this behaviour.

```
...
   ports:
      - 25565-25570:25565
...
```